# Logging from pyspark application to a local or hdfs file

Tags: pyspark

I have an application in pyspark includes closure functions that contain logging statements, I don't know how to log messages to local/hdfs file in pyspark.
I tried something as below but doesn't work:

```
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext
import logging

def parse_json(text_line):
    try:
        return(json.loads(text_line))
    except ValueError:
        # here I need to log a warning message to a local file or even to default spark logs
        logger.warn("invalid json structure" + text_line)
        return({})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_data = ['{"id": "111", "name": "aaa"}',
               '{"wrong json", "name": "bbb"}',
               '{"id": "333", "name": "ccc"}']
    sc = SparkContext()
    logger = logging.getLogger('py4j')
    lines = sc.parallelize(my_data)
    my_data_json = lines.map(parse_json).filter(lambda x: x)
    print(my_data_json.collect())
```

Any help please!

Comment: could you define "doesn't work"? do you get an error or "nothing happens"?

Comment: I get no error but I don't find any log message in driver or executors log files.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the log4j appender in your log4j setting and use it inside your pyspark application. I haven't tried storing logs on HDFS, however this method will definitely help you get started with logging onto console and locally to files.

I have written a small blog post to address your solution.

https://www.shantanualshi.com/logging-in-pyspark/2016-07-04-logging-in-pyspark-scripts/

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thanks @Shantanu Alshi for the post. Actually I applied your instructions and I got the warning on the screen but I didn't find it anywhere in the log files. nothing in spark/logs/ nor in /tmp/logfile.out

Comment: Hey @K.Ali, In addition to console, also add FILE to your rootlogger property.  -- log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console, FILE

Comment: Thanks @Shantanu Alshi and sorry for late reaction. Now I I get the massage in logfile.out too but I also get all spark logs as well in the same file. do you think I can get my application logs separated without spark logs?

Comment: Sorry @Shantanu Alshi, according to my question, I need to log from closure function which will be distributed on the executors not only from the driver. How can I distribute you logger `log` to be known in mapped functions?

Comment: Still stuck here, any idea? @zero323